# Aligning a navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just created a a navbar and a hover feature.But the problems are now that when I hover on HOME,BEDROOMS and CONTACT US,the color has no effect entirely from top to bottom on the navbar...but on the others(Eg: FACILITIES SERVICES) the color has full effect.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-top:10px">
        <li><span class="details"><strong>Phone</strong> </span><span           class="contacts">021 913 0643</span></li>
        <br/>
        <span class="details"><strong>Email</strong> </span> <a     class="contacts" href="#">info@acaciahouse.co.za </a>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span ></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span ></span> FACILITIES<br/>
          SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BEDROOMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RATEs <br/>
          & BOOKINGS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SURROUNDING<br/>
          ATTRACTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
    padding: 0 px;
    background: #331a00;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    border: 0px;
}

.navbar ul.navbar-right li a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul.navbar-right li a:hover{
    background:#000000;
}
```

Check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nuouxap5/1/)

Comment: Like this : https://jsfiddle.net/nuouxap5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to used `min-height: 90px;` to `.navbar-nav.navbar-right li` and `display` property for `.navbar-nav.navbar-right li` and `.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a`.

To make text vertically middle use below css.

**Updated CSS**

```
.navbar{
    background: #331a00;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    color: #ffffff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 }
.navbar .navbar-default {
    background:none;
    border:0;
}

.navbar ul.navbar-right li a:hover{
    background:#000000;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar ul li a{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right li{
    display:table;
    min-height:90px;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right li{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    min-height:60px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse{
    max-height: inherit;
  }
  .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ayj7o36/17/)

Comment: Works perfectly for the the weight.The new challenge now is that the alignment is not perfect.
Eg: The FACILITIES SERVICES is properly on the center,but the Home aligns to theFACILITIES SERVICES of being position a bit further down so it could be properly aligned to the center(top&bottom) between Facilities Services.
Just to remember that FACILITIES SERVICES are not in the same line.

Comment: In small devices(when the navbar collapses), the same problem happens to the hover option but in this case is from left to right.
Meaning that if I hover on HOME,only the little section will turn black.
How can I make that to turn black entirely on the navbar from left to right?

Comment: It helps a lot.Is there a way that I can a give a unique size to the padding when I hover the lists?
Because I can see that when I hover on HOME,it turns black yes,but the size of the same black section is smaller comparing to the one on the FACILITIES SERVICES.

Comment: Which size are you talking about??

Comment: Eg:When you hover on HOME it turns black all the way from left to right and obviously from TOP to BOTTOM around the HOME link.
The same applies to other links.
The problem is that as I hover each of those links and it keeps on turning black the size of the padding(TOP to BOTTOM ) is different for each link.

Just to emphasize that am referring to that when the navbar is on the collapsing mode.

Comment: You want same size in collapsing mode too like full mode, right??

Comment: Yes.In a way that the paddings of the black portion get the same for all links on the top and the bottom... just the way it is from left to right.

Comment: Surely I need to increase on the vote of your answer Sunil.It works perfectly

Comment: Well I am not expert on the procedures of Stack overflow yet with regards to what to do when a help is given. But I guess already clicked on your  answer button.Thanks a lot for the help and let me know where else to click if necessary
Unfortunately I still do not have enough reputation to chat.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this CSS code works perfectly:

```
    @import  url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
   .navbar{
    background: #331a00;
    }
.navbar ul li a{
color: #ffffff !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar .navbar-default {
background:none;
border:0;
}

.navbar ul.navbar-right li a:hover{
background:#000000;
}
     @media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar ul li a{
     text-align:center;
     }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right li{
     display:table;
     min-height:90px;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    }
            @media (max-width: 767px){
   .navbar-nav.navbar-right li{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    min-height:60px;
   }
   .navbar-collapse{
    max-height: inherit;
   }
   .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
          }
```